# How do I set Authorization Bearer header with nodejs

Tags: node.js, authentication, header, authorization, bearer-token

I am working on a signup page and I am lost trying to set the Authorization Bearer Header. I am using jsonwebtokens to generate the token. I know how to set the header on postman, but how do I set it for the actual route I’m signing up to and be able to use it in my auth middleware for other endpoints ? As postman is just for tests

Answer (score 2):

```
request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+accessToken)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set headers inside request in your route. Using `request` module.

```
app.post('/test', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("inside the test");
    request.post({
      url: api_address,
      body: JSON.stringify(send),
      headers: {
         "Content-Type":"application/json",
         "Authorization": "Bearer 71D50F9987529"
}
    }, function (error, response, body) {
      console.log("hiii");
      console.log(response.statusCode);
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Successful call
        var results = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(results) // View Results
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: I don’t want to do it in postman, I want to set the authorization straight from my post route in node

Comment: As a trick you can use postman to generate the code for you in any language.